# Segmentation error when I use double pointers in C to find determinant of an array

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

I'm trying to write a code in C that calculates the determinant of given n * n matrix, but I end up getting segmentation fault in the function *get_subarray* even though I have not exceeded the last index anywhere.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ll long long

void print_2d(int **arr, int n){
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
            printf("%d ", arr[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n\n");
}

ll base_case(int **arr, int n){
    //for n = 2
    ll res = arr[0][0] * arr[1][1] - arr[1][0] * arr[0][1];

    return res;
}

void get_subarray(int **arr, int **sub_arr, int n, int col){
    int i = 0, j = 0;

    // print_2d(arr, n);

    for(int k = 1; k < n; k++){
        j = 0;
        
        for(int m = 0; m < n; m++){

            if(m != col && j < n - 1 && i < n - 1){
                // printf("%d %d\t%d %d\n", i, j, k, m);
                sub_arr[i][j] = arr[k][m];
                j++;
            }

        }
        i++;
        // printf("\n");
    }
}

ll get_determinant(int **arr, int n){

    if(n == 2){
        return base_case(arr, n); 
    }

    ll det = 0;
    ll tmp;

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){        
        int **sub_arr = (int**)malloc((n - 1) * sizeof(int *));

        for(int j = 0; j < n - 1; j++){
            sub_arr[i] = (int*) malloc((n - 1) * sizeof(int));
        }

        get_subarray(arr, sub_arr, n, i);

        //print_2d(sub_arr, n - 1);

        tmp = arr[0][i] * get_determinant(sub_arr, n - 1);

        det += tmp;
    }

    return det;
};

int main() {
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);

    int **arr = (int **) malloc(n * sizeof(int*));

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        arr[i] = (int*) malloc(n * sizeof(int));

        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
            scanf("%d", &arr[i][j]);
        }
    }

    ll res = get_determinant(arr, n);
    printf("%lld", res);

    return 0;
}
```

I tried debugging the code and at function *get_subarray* after the execution reaches index `i = 1` and `j = 0` or `k = 2` and `m = 1`, I get segmentation fault/error.

I tried this same logic using vectors in C++ and it is showing the correct answer, but in C I am getting segmentation error.

Comment: What input to do give the program and what is the expected output?

Comment: This looks fishy... are you sure you want to be assigning to 'i' in this step...
            sub_arr[i] = (int*) malloc((n - 1) * sizeof(int));
If nothing else this is a memory leak since you lose the pointer being allocated by not storing it in say sub_arr[i][j].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create an array "subarray" with size n-1, then iterate over it from  j = 0 to n - 1 but always assign to subarray[i] instead of subarry[j]. Why is the way to create a "subarray" different from an "array"? Create one function that can return matrix with some size.

```
int **sub_arr = (int**)malloc((n - 1) * sizeof(int *));
for(int j = 0; j < n - 1; j++) {
     sub_arr[i] = (int*) malloc((n - 1) * sizeof(int)); // <--  
}
```

If the function is called get_subarray, then why not return the array itself directly from it, so you can avoid such errors.